# How to Display Wrapper Class Variable in Apex Controller

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

Find the link and provide me the solution for that.

I could paste the code here directly,so fine the link

[click here to view the code](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000BdwuQAC)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000BdwuQAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Restaurantwrapper.cls_nearby_restaurants nearby_restaurant : Restaurantwrapper.nearby_restaurants){
    String name = nearby_restaurant.restaurant.name;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gareth Jordan,  Its works perfectly,   Kindly give solution for another question.check the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907565/how-to-display-static-liststring-in-vf-page